# wxPython: how to search for text in a TextCtrl?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I feel like I must be missing something completely obvious, but I don't see how to search for text in a multi line textctrl. Is there an API for searching forwards and backwards through a text control?

I do not want suggestions involving the FindReplaceDialog, that's not an option I wish to explore. I will be creating an entry widget and want to search for whatever the user types in. I know how to do the bindings and whatnot, I just don't see how to find occurrences of a string within a TextCtrl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the SCiTE widget... it should blow Tk's text widget out of the water.  It's integrated into [wxPython's stc module](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl-class.html#SearchNext)

Comment: I'm not sure about the "blow Tk's text widget out of the water" comment. The python widget has more features but I don't think it's quite as elegant or easy to use. <shrug>.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're expected to get the text using [GetValue](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxtextctrl.html#wxtextctrlgetvalue) and search it as a string.

Comment: Actually just .Value .  You don't need to call getters explicitly in Python.

Comment: You gotta be kidding me!? So I have to keep track of rows and columns myself, as well as the overhead of duplicating my data? (one copy owned by the control, one copy for searching).  *sigh*. I guess I've become spoiled by Tk's incredible text widget. I sure hope someone comes up with a better answer.